# Prove that a function is uniformly continuous if exists a constant $c$ such that for all $x,y$ from the domain of the function $|f(x)-f(y)|\le c|x-y|$

Tags: calculus, general-topology, continuity

> Prove that a function is uniformly continuous if there exists a
>   constant $c$ such that for all $x,y$ from the domain of the function
>   $|f(x)-f(y)|\le c|x-y|$

I've spent some time thinking about this, but to no avail. I, however, figured out a few things: 
(1) In the case when these two expressions are actually equal, this is a linear function which is uniformly continuous. 
(2) The slope of the function is always at most $c$, therefore $f(x) < cx$
 
I don't know if these observations are useful. 
Any hints would be most appreciated.

Comment: Your task is: Given $\epsilon>0$, find $\delta>0$ such that $|x-y|<\epsilon$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)|<\delta$. Can you see how you could pick $\delta$ in terms of $\epsilon$ and $c$? If $|x-y|<\epsilon$, what does the given condition tell you?

Comment: What **definition** of "uniform continuity" are you using?  The result you want to prove is what I learned as the definition.

Comment: @user247327: You're thinking of Lipschitz continuity. For uniform continuity, there will be a possibly nonlinear [modulus of continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulus_of_continuity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f:D \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is uniformly continuous in

$D$, if

for every $\epsilon >0$ there is a $\delta$ such that

$|x-x'| \lt \delta$ implies

$|f(x)-f(x')| \lt \epsilon$ for all $x,x' \in D.$

Given:

$|f(x)-f(x')| \le c|x-x'|$,  $c>0$, for $ x,x' \in D.$

Let $ \epsilon$ be given.

Choose $\delta =\epsilon/c.$

Then for $x,x' \in D:$

$|x-x'| \lt \delta$ implies

$|f(x)-f(x')| \le c|x-x'| \lt c\delta = \epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

You want, given a $\epsilon$, a $\delta$ which will work for any points in the domain of your function.

You have a direct control over the distance between values in the range by values in the domain however, $|f(x)-f(y)|< c|x-y|$. Hence, if 
$$
|x-y|<\delta/c 
$$
then 
$$
|f(x)-f(y)|<\delta
$$
and this holds everywhere in your domain. Can you see what you should select as your delta to match any epsilon challenge?